# Datepicker não renderizar próximos meses?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Temos este exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/3eBLH/. Quando eu clico no més de maio, ele renderiza os próximos 2 meses.

Tem como desabilitar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema se encontra no metodo onSelect, quando você Seleciona a data você tenta instanciar novamente, fazendo com que siga para os próximos meses.

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date-from").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date-to").val());
    return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
  },
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date-from").val());
    var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date-to").val());
    if (!date1 || date2) {
      $("#date-from").val(dateText);
      $("#date-to").val("");
      //  $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", dateText);
    } else {
      $("#date-to").val(dateText);
      //  $(this).datepicker("option", "minDate", null);
    }
  }
});
```

As linhas comentadas são o seu problema, o que você esta tentando fazer nelas pode estar errado.

O legal seria fazer algo assim: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/3eBLH/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Este artigo me ajudou bastante:

http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3604/calendario-em-jquery-criando-calendarios-com-datepicker.aspx